CashApp to checking
Someone wants to put money on my CashApp account and then I can transfer to my checking account. My question is does this give them any access to my checking account? They are not on my checking account. I’ve never used CashApp and I’m nervous.
Thanks

CashApp is a mobile payment app developed by Square -- a major payment processor. It's a reputable company and real app that indeed lets you transfer money. Basically a Venmo alternative.

@BenjaminKuykendall CashApp may be a legitimate thing, but be aware that if this is a scammer (very likely), they may well send the OP a link to a fake CashApp site from where they can steal the OP's bank details.

Who is "Them" in this question?


Why? Unless there is a very good reason and you know this individual well in real life (not just on the internet), presume you are being scammed.

I know nothing about CashApp. What information are they going to need in order to do this, and does giving out that information put you at risk? (Does it expose your own banking info, for example?)


2.5) Are they asking only for information that CashApp legitimately needs, or are they using it as an excuse to ask for more info, eg to "fix a problem"? Are they asking you to use a specific URI to access CashApp rather than telling you to find the published one? Either means scam or identity theft.

What are they asking you to do in return? If it involves sending money to anyone else, assume scam and/or money laundering.

If they ask you to spend any money to get this money, assume scam.

See #1.


(If you had just said "someone wants to pay me by CashApp, is it safe?", you might get a different answer. "Put money into" is the kind of phrase I would expect in a scam.)
